Deeper Contextual understanding of Isaiah 58:7 "Not to hide yourself from your own flesh"

Isaiah 58:7 New American Standard Bible 1995
7    (a) “Is it not to
divide your bread [a]with the hungry (b) And bring the homeless poor
into the house; (c) When you see the naked, to cover him; (d) And not
to hide yourself from your own flesh?


Isaiah 58:7
New King James Version
7     (a) Is it not to share your
bread with the hungry, (b) And that you bring to your house the poor
who are [a]cast out; (c) When you see the naked, that you cover him,
(d) And not hide yourself from your own flesh?


Isaiah 58:7
English Standard Version
7   (a) Is it not to share your
bread with the hungry
(b) and bring the homeless poor into your house; (c) when you see the naked, to cover him,
(d) and not to hide yourself from your own flesh?


58:7
The Westminster Leningrad Codex
7 הֲל֨וֹא פָרֹ֤ס לָֽרָעֵב֙
לַחְמֶ֔ךָ וַעֲנִיִּ֥ים מְרוּדִ֖ים תָּ֣בִיא בָ֑יִת כִּֽי־תִרְאֶ֤ה
עָרֹם֙ וְכִסִּית֔וֹ וּמִבְּשָׂרְךָ֖ לֹ֥א תִתְעַלָּֽם׃

It would be interesting to delve into the contextual meaning behind
Isaiah 58:7(d)
And not to hide yourself from your own flesh?
https://biblehub.com/commentaries/isaiah/58-7.htm
Many of the commentaries on biblehub seem to suggest that said verse is stating that one should Not hide oneself from

Either kinship as in blood relatives
Or the more general view of people belonging to mankind

Could someone please read the Hebrew translation of Isaiah 58:7 , and provide an exegesis on Isaiah 58:7(d) ?

The idea here is that one should clothe the naked and not turn away (hide oneself) from one's "own flesh" in the sense of one's own "flesh and blood." But this is not limited to one's relatives alone. It is meant to be seen through the lens of the teaching of  Leviticus 19:34:

You shall treat the alien who resides with you no differently than the
natives born among you; you shall love the alien as yourself.

Seen this way, hiding oneself from his own flesh signifies turning away from one's neighbor, including foreigners.

Ellicott offers this remark:

From thine own flesh.—Usage, as in Genesis 29:14; Nehemiah 5:5, leads
us to refer the words primarily to suffering Israelites, but those who
have learnt that “God hath made of one blood all the nations of the
earth” (Acts 17:26) will extend its range to every form of suffering
humanity.

Jesus also answered the OP's question when He told the story of the good Samaritan - one's neighbor is anyone in need.
Thus, hiding from one's own flesh is, in this context, ignoring the needs of the needy, whether immediate family or anyone else.
